# Full Calendar 4 - get events after calendar loads

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, fullcalendar, vue-component, fullcalendar-4

I want to call the function in that call back to make getting events with ajax, I do not want to load all with the page load. I tried doing this in datesRender and other main method, but it is not worked well for me because i want to be callback it once.

Is there a callback in Vue.js full calendar which is called after the calendar has rendered completely??

Comment: "I want to call the function in that call back to make getting events with ajax"...that's what either https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-json-feed or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-function can do. Use one of those options if you want to load your events gradually

Comment: thanks bro, but i don't mean that, please read my question one more time and check this link you will get my Question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272005/jquery-full-calendar-callback-after-the-calendar-has-loaded-completely

Comment: You said _"I want to call the function in that call back to make getting events with ajax not load all with page load"_ ... the links I posted allow you to do that. i.e, you don't need to load all the events at the start, instead each time you change the view and/or the date, fullCalendar will load only the events which are relevant to that view. The link you've posted is talking about getting events which are previously downloaded, not getting them via AJAX - it doesn't seem to be relevant to your request. If you think it is, then you need to explain your real question more clearly.

Comment: Thanks bro for your anser, i just want one way to tell me when fullcalendar loaded and ready to call callback , but i want to be that callback load once why? i want to add lestener to prev/next button in fullcalender i know there are few methods like datesRender but i have more than one view so it callback it more than one.

Comment: "i want to add lestener to prev/next button in fullcalender"....why? What will you do when these buttons are pressed? There is no listener for those in fullCalendar, because it's almost never necessary to handle them.

Comment: yes you are right bro, i know there are not default listener, it is not problem i can make listener with jQuery but it need timeout and i don't want to make that listener with timeout, for that i want a callback when fullcalendar ready like $(document).ready for fullcalendar to make that listener/my action.

Comment: Yes I know that, but my question was **why** do you want to do that? If you want to load events, I've already told you a better way to do that

Comment: @ADyson, I think it depends on how one interprets his question as to whether it has any merit. I certainly have a need to simply register a callback/hook upon complete loading of the view (for instance, if I wanted to scroll to the current day) and I've only had luck using hacky work-arounds that have some major caveats.